# New Outlook Double (two step) Authentication on Mail Clients like thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, email

I am using Thunderbird without any issue until I enabled two way authentication in my Outlook account.

Since then on  start up, my Thunderbird is asking to enter a new password and I have to recreate a new apppassword by going to my account settings via browser.

Any good alternative to this procedure??

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why is this in the Ubuntu S.E? It seems to apply to anyone using Firebird and Office 365

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you enable 2-step verification feature, some programs such as Windows Live Mail, Thunderbird, etc will not allow you to sign in using your current password. It happens because these kind of programs don't support 2-step verification security codes. To solve this problem, you'll need to create App password using simple steps given here : http://www.askvg.com/fix-mail-apps-and-devices-shows-incorrect-password-error-after-enabling-2-step-verification-in-microsoft-or-gmail-account/